# Connecting to SAP B1 database and pushing entries into it through PHP

Tags: php, sapb1

I'm a newbie to SAP, please help me connecting and pushing entries on SAP database through PHP

```
<?php
echo "SBO PHP TEST<br>";
$vCmp=new COM("PERPETUA.company") or die ("No connection");
$vCmp->server = "(localhost)";
$vCmp->CompanyDB = "SYSTEM";
$vCmp->LicenseServer = "localhost:30000";
$vCmp->username = "manager";
$vCmp->password = "manager";
$vCmp->DbServerType(PERPETUA.BoDataServerTypes.dst_MSSQL2008);
$lRetCode = $vCmp->Connect;
echo $vCmp->CompanyName;
echo '<br>';
$vItem = $vCmp->GetBusinessObject(oItems);
$RetVal = $vItem->GetByKey("A1010");
echo '$vItem->Itemname';
echo '<br><br>Ready';
?>
```

This did not work.

1. How to connect to the SAP B1 database?
2. How entries are pushed into PHP to SAP B1 database?

Answer (score 0):

Are there some errors when you connecting to B1?

What means `PERPETUA`? 
Try replace `PERPETUA` with `SAPbobsCOM`.
Maybe you have to add database username and password:

```
$vCmp->DbUserName = "sa";
$vCmp->DbPassword = "******";
$vCmp->UseTrusted = false;
```

The B1 server address should be the same like in SLD.
If you use 'localhost' in SLD so type localhost in DIAPI.
If you use the machine name or ip-address use this in DIAPI instead of localhost.

Additional information: http://scn.sap.com/message/2013907#2013907

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
$vCmp=new COM("PERPETUA.company") or die ("No connection");
```

To

```
$vCmp=new COM("SAPbobsCOM.PERPETUA") or die ("No connection");
```